# Call to stored procedure fails in classic asp when the stored proc INSERTs or UPDATEs tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp-classic

I am developing/maintaining **classic asp pages** and asp code on a Windows 7 PC with data taking from an **Sqlserver/Express 2008/R2**.

In this code I use a stored procedure to log-on to the web site.

- If the login-id and password combination is correct some tables are updated using UPDATE or INSERT.
- If the login-id or password is not correct, no logging is issued( so no tables are updated ).

**A result set is returned** with some fields on both cases (with a field set to -1 or the internal user nr depending on the correctness of login-id and password).

*I have been using this same routine for over 5 years now , running on all sorts of IIS servers and with all sorts of Sqlservers.*

The code, which works on other IIS/Sqlservers combinations does not work on my development PC.

Any idea why?

Since it is a development environment I use the sqlserver SA account with the appropriate password. So as far as I can tell, this SA user should have all appropriate rights.

To be complete I will now give the routine ( but you will see it's very straight forward ):

```vb
  function DoLogon( byval psNickName, byval psPassword)

     dim sSql

     DoLogon = False

     psNickName = Trim(psNickName)
     psPassword = Trim(psPassword)

     if (psNickName = "") then exit function
     if (psPassword = "") then exit function

   '  on error Resume Next

     call DbOpen

     sSql = "exec sp_EcomLogon " & SqlString( psNickName ) & "," & _
                              SqlString(psPassWord) & "," & _
                              SqlString(Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")) & "," & _
                              Trim(cStr(Session.SessionId))

     objRec.Open sSql ,objConn  ' ,adOpenStatic,adLockReadOnly ,adCmdText

     Klant_NetId = FldDft("K_NetId",-1)

     Call SetVarValue(cKlant_NetId,Klant_NetId)
     objRec.Close
     call DbClose

     if Klant_NetId <> -1 then
        DoLogon = True
        Klant_IsLoggedOn = 1
     else
        DoLogon = False
        Klant_IsLoggedOn = 0
     end if
     call  SetVarValue(cKlant_IsLoggedOn, Klant_IsLoggedOn)

  end function
```

The following error is displayed when the `objRec.Close` line is present:

```
ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78'

Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.
```

- Replacing the `exec sp_...` with a `select * from ...` works. So I presume the code it self is correct.
- DbOpen and DbClose will allocate `objRec` and `objConn` and connect to / disconnect from the server (here SqlServer).

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION**

I have asked the person providing me with this solution to create an answer so I can give him proper upvotes, but in the mean time I will present the solution here.

As the first statement if the stored procedure I have added

set nocount on

And this seems to be the trick to get it working.

I have not found why this is necessary (from a technically view point), just that including `set nocount on` will speed up the stored procedures, but at last I have running stored procedures in combination with classic ASP again !

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  Do you get an exception?  One possible explanation might be that Win7 runs IIS7, which in "integrated mode", is not entirely compatible with IIS6

Comment: @Andomar: I said so: the call to `objRec.Close` gives a `Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.` message , indicating that the `objRec.Open ...` call did not succeed.

Comment: Try to add `set nocount on` at the top of the stored procedure?

Comment: @Andomar : No , that doesn't work .

Comment: What happens when you Reponse.Write "sSql"?  Does it look correct?  My guess is that some parameter isn't being appended to your sSql string.

Comment: @BradBrening The sql is correct, I always debug(Response.Write) my queries in case of trouble. Executing the exact query in a database program ( I use Database Workbench ) works. I has to be something to do with permissions, but since I am already using the sa account, I don't see where the problem could be.

Comment: @Andomar Can you provide your comment as an answer. Because this was indeed the solution. Putting `set nocount on` as the first line of serveral procedures was required to let them run and return a recordset to the ASP code. I cannot explain why (technically) and I have to verify this with other Sqlservers, but at least on my Sqlserver/Express 2008 installation, the procedure now work with ASP as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `set nocount on` to the top of the stored procedure?

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the stored procedure that you are accessing is executing with an error.  I would suggest that you write out the string sSql to screen copy it and execute it in query analyser to troubleshoot it.

Comment: The sql is correct, I always debug(Response.Write) my queries in case of trouble. Executing the exact query in a database program ( I use Database Workbench ) works. I has to be something to do with permissions, but since I am already using the sa account, I don't see where the problem could be.

Comment: Try profiling your database call with a profiler such as Anj Profiler http://anjlab.com/en/projects/opensource/sqlprofiler to view which account is executing the stored procedure etc

Comment: +1 for mentioning the profiler . This at least verified to met that the correct accounts were used to run the storec procedures AND that the syntax of the stored procedure was correct. Investigating further I found out that putting `set nocount on` on top of several procedures was required. Don't know why, but that solved the problem. I have asked @Andomar (who provided this solution as a comment) to make his comment into an answer.

Comment: Edelcom - glad to help - its useful to be able to see those calls with clarity. @Andomar deserves the points.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and in my case the issue was permissions on the table I was selecting from.  I didn't have select permissions and it would close the connection.  Now you mentioned that you are using the sa account so this should have permissions to all the functionality, but I would double check to make sure that this is true.  HTH

Wade

Comment: Double checked this before asking the question here. Executing the `exec sp_...` in a database client program , works.

Comment: @edelcom This error sucks since it never shows you the correct error.  Can I assume you looked at the sql server logs as well to see if there is any error?